# copy and paste from xlsm to csv

Tags: excel, vba, csv, copy-paste, xlsm

I am trying to copy from a macro enabled workbook to a .csv file, but for some reason the paste part paste everything in Column A only. VBA coding is below. Please help me figure out why it will not paste into the same cells as it copies. When I run the macro step by step it works perfect, however when it runs by itself it paste all data in Column A.

```
Sheets("Input").Select

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\temp\MyFile.csv"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1):

### Export Worksheet to CSV

**An Alternative**

- If whatever you are trying to select is the only data in the worksheet, you can just [`copy the worksheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy), which creates a new workbook containing only this worksheet and finally save it as a CSV file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheetToCSVtest()
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\temp\MyFile.csv"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
    ExportWorksheetToCSV ws, FilePath
End Sub

Sub ExportWorksheetToCSV( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FilePath As String)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ws.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs FilePath, xlCSV
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with improved answer.**

Not sure what you're doing wrong with your sheet, but this will work. Don't use Select.

```
Dim CopyRange As Range, copySheet As Worksheet
Set copySheet = ActiveSheet

Set CopyRange = Intersect(Range("A:C"), copySheet.UsedRange)

Dim theValues()

theValues = CopyRange.Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\temp\MyFile.csv"
Dim theCSV As Workbook
    Set theCSV = ActiveWorkbook
theCSV.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(theValues), UBound(theValues, 2)) = theValues
```

Answer (score 0):

@PGSystemTester: This code did the same thing. Everything is pasted in Column A only.

@VBasic2008: This worked, but also gave unexpected errors.

What I did to make it work was basically run the same macro twice. I am not sure why this works. But the first time the macro runs, it pastes everything in Column A. When it runs again, it pastes correctly. So I just doubled the coding for the macro and now it works fine.

Thanks for the help!